# Add async await support for PCL library

Tags: async-await, portable-class-library

I'm creating PCL library to be used at Windows Store 8.0 and Windows Phone 7.5 clients.
I created new PCL project and chose the following:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/pcl_profile4.png

Selected profile covers .net 4.5 and silverlight 4.0 thus they were enabled automatically.
As a result I have Profile4 selected but when I'm trying to add Async nuget package to PCL project:
http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async

```
I'm getting an error that this profile is not supported:
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl (≥ 1.0.19)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build (≥ 1.0.4)'.
'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10' already installed.
'Microsoft.Bcl 1.0.19' already installed.
'Microsoft.Bcl.Async 1.0.16' already installed.
Adding 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10' to PortableClassLibrary1.
Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.10'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+sl40+wp', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How to create PCL library and add Async/Await support WITHOUT cheating the *.csproj file (I know I can specify profile there but I need to be able to it via UI for DEMO purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project is targeting Windows Phone 7.0, not 7.1/7.5. Change your target to "Windows Phone 7.5 and higher".

For best results, uninstall all NuGet packages, change your targets, and then re-install your NuGet packages.

Comment: I shown the screenshot above where I'm choosing WP 7.5. Visual Studio downgrades WP version automatically

Comment: I also see in that screenshot that you're using the "hacked" profiles for Mono. Note that Mono now has proper PCL support and the hacked profiles should no longer be used. When I follow your exact steps on VS2012 (unhacked), VS adds .NET 4.5 and SL4 for a final profile of `Profile104` (not `Profile4`). You may be able to fix your hacked reference asseblies by using [an app I wrote](https://github.com/StephenCleary/PortableLibraryProfiles) and comparing the results against [what I got](http://embed.plnkr.co/ljoEYxIu0e9xXRsibEoI).